# Reload environment variables

Tags: emacsclient, environment

This question has been asked at superuser [is-there-a-way-to-reload-environment-variables-in-emacs](https://superuser.com/questions/462492/is-there-a-way-to-reload-environment-variables-in-emacs), but no good solution was given.

I am using EmacsClient with often more than 30 buffers open, if I change an environment variable in the shell, I need to exit EmacsClient ( and reopen all the buffers) or I have to manually set the environment variable also in Emacs. I find it annoying that I cannot update the environment variables easily in Emacs. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do this, because changing an environment variable in the parent process will not update its value as exported to a child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, the following can be used (Linux, Bash):

- First run `printenv -0 > env.txt` from the Bash terminal window,
- Then from within Emacs, run

```el
(defun my-update-env ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((str 
         (with-temp-buffer
           (insert-file-contents "env.txt")
           (buffer-string))) lst)
    (setq lst (split-string str "\000"))
    (while lst
      (setq cur (car lst))
      (when (string-match "^\\(.*?\\)=\\(.*\\)" cur)
        (setq var (match-string 1 cur))
        (setq value (match-string 2 cur))
        (setenv var value))
      (setq lst (cdr lst)))))
```

**Update**

I turns out that this can be done more elegantly using the `--eval` option of the `emacsclient` command: Define a Bash script `update_emacs_env`:

```
#! /bin/bash

fn=tempfile
printenv -0 > "$fn" 
emacsclient -s server_name -e '(my-update-env "'"$fn"'")' >/dev/null
```

where `server_name` is your Emacs server name, and `my-update-env` is a function defined by your `~/.emacs` file:

```el
(defun my-update-env (fn)
  (let ((str 
         (with-temp-buffer
           (insert-file-contents fn)
           (buffer-string))) lst)
    (setq lst (split-string str "\000"))
    (while lst
      (setq cur (car lst))
      (when (string-match "^\\(.*?\\)=\\(.*\\)" cur)
        (setq var (match-string 1 cur))
        (setq value (match-string 2 cur))
        (setenv var value))
      (setq lst (cdr lst)))))
```

Now you can simply type `update_emacs_env` from the shell command line to update the Emacs environment variables..

Comment: And you could run the "printenv" from inside the function too...

Comment: @mankoff Actually, I think you could not.. :) (It would print the old values then)

Comment: Can't you spawn a shell with login flag? Or `source` the .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.?

Comment: Yes.. but it would not help for the special case if I export in the shell directly from command line, using `export VAR=value`

Comment: Yes I didn't think of that case. Elegant solution with the client!

Answer (score 9):

[exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) provides the `exec-path-from-shell-copy-env` command, which lets you copy the value of environment variables to Emacs sessions.  For instance, `M-x exec-path-from-shell-copy-env RET FOO` sets the value of `$FOO` in Emacs as well.

Note that `exec-path-from-shell-copy-env` spawns a **new** shell to extract the value of the environment variable.  Hence it will only work for variables that you set in your shell configuration files (e.g. `.bashrc`), but not for variables only set in a running shell session with `export`.  Extracting these variables is generally impossible without convoluted hacks that inspect `/proc/` or similar API for running processes.

Comment: Regarding the latter/transient values, if Emacs is running as a server then passing the updated values through to emacsclient directly from that shell would be easy enough.

Comment: @phils Thanks, see my updated answer..

Answer (score 3):

I used to use this:

```sh
function export-emacs {
    if [ "$(emacsclient -e t)" != 't' ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    for name in "${@}"; do
        value=$(eval echo \"\$${name}\")
        emacsclient -e "(setenv \"${name}\" \"${value}\")" >/dev/null
    done
}
```

Lets you export a named variable, E.G:

```
export EDITOR=vim
export-emacs EDITOR
```