# load environment variables of virtual environment in emacs

Tags: python, variables, environment

What is the best way to load in emacs the environment variables of a virtualenv?

I seem to have got virtualenvwrapper.el working.  For example, after using `venv-workon my_venv`, then `M-! printenv` shows that the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` has been set to `my_venv`.  Likewise, different virtualenvs load different python versions.

It also seems that I've got the package exec-path-from-shell.el working.  For example, in the terminal outside of any virtualenv the command  `printenv` shows `MY_ENV_VARIABLE=oy`. Now after doing `(exec-path-from-shell "MY_ENV_VARIABLE")` inside emacs, `M-! printenv` confirms that `MY_ENV_VARIABLE=oy` inside emacs as well.

So, I tried doing `venv-workon my_venv` and then  `exec-path-from-shell MY_VENV_VARIABLE`, which has been set in `my_venv`.  Then, `exec-path-from-shell` seems to find the value of `MY_VENV_VARIABLE` to be `nil` while actually it is `voy`.

Comment: Well... there are too many unknowns... but a relatively easy way to achieve something like this (w/o using third-party packages) would be to parse the output of `printenv` and use the results with `(setenv "variable-name" "variable-value")`.

Comment: See also [Reload environment variables](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/reload-environment-variables/6107#6107)

Comment: Ah i see!  So the strategy I'd tried is really a nonstarter.  But the workaround in that linked answer ...works :).  Thank you.